# Martingale representation of a stopped Brownian motion

Tags: stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus, martingales

This question follows from the previous post [Question on the martingale representation theorem](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/398025/question-on-the-martingale-representation-theorem) which has not been answered. I consider thus a particular case. Let $(B_t)_{t\ge 0}$ be a standard Brownian motion and $\tau:=\inf\{t\ge 0: |B_t|=1\}$. Then $(B_{t\wedge \tau})_{t\ge 0}$ is a Markov martingale. Therefore, if my claim in [Question on the martingale representation theorem](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/398025/question-on-the-martingale-representation-theorem) is correct,  then there exists some Brownian motion $(W_t)_{t\ge 0}$ s.t.

$$B_{t\wedge \tau}=\int_0^t\sigma(s, B_{s\wedge \tau})dW_s,\quad \forall t\ge 0.$$

Could we identify $\sigma$ for this case?

Comment: I guess one can simply set $B_t = W_t$, $\sigma(s,x)=1$ if $|x|<1$ and $\sigma(s,x)=0$ if $|x|=1$?

Comment: @MateuszKwaśnicki  Your observation is amazing! It's absolutely right. What I thought is to compare the quadratic variation, which yields $t\wedge \tau=\int_0^t |\sigma(s,B_{s\wedge \tau})|^2ds$. But then I don't know how to get $\sigma$...

Comment: @MateuszKwaśnicki So, for this case, the existence of $\sigma$ is ensured for this particular case. As the general case, see my previous post https://mathoverflow.net/questions/398025/question-on-the-martingale-representation-theorem, do you believe it is still true?